# How to remove garbage data from a temp table based on several criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql Server version: Sql Server 2019 - 15.04138.2
Here is the script to generate the data in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #data 
(
    Device varchar(100), 
    Hall INT, 
    EquipNo INT, 
    LocNo INT, 
    HitCount INT, 
    Operator VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #data
    VALUES 
          ('Tiger', 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 0, 10, 0, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 0, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 0, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 3, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 3, 'Sam')  

        , ('Shark', 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, 0, 0, null) 
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, null, 5, null) 
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, 20, 2, null)
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, 20, 2, 'Alex')

        , ('Tiger', 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 3, 0, 0, null) 
        , ('Tiger', 1, null, null, 5, null)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 3, 20, 10, 'Sam') 
        , ('Tiger', 1, 3, 20, 2, 'Sam')
```

In the above data, a record is valid if it has values in Device, Hall, EquipNo and HitCount columns, other than zero or empty string. The data can be grouped logically by Device, Hall and EquipNo. If 2 records in a group have "Device, hall, EquipNo and HitCount" data then we need to select the record with the highest value for HitCount. But if the hitcount is the same then we should take the record with the most information.

The desired result is (order is not important):

| Device | Hall | EquipNo | LocNo | HitCount | Operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tiger | 1 | 5 | 10 | 3 | Sam |
| Shark | 2 | 3 | Null | 5 | Null |
| Tiger | 1 | 3 | 20 | 10 | Sam |

As an additional clarification, please see the following image to see what data we should end up with:
[records to be selected](https://ibb.co/5sKDPqj)

Using another temporary table or more is ok to end up with the desired result.

---

---

UPDATE:
Here is the updated script to create a temp table with test data and applying solution provided by Hogan:

```
CREATE TABLE #data 
(
    Device varchar(100), 
    Hall INT, 
    EquipNo INT, 
    LocNo INT, 
    HitCount INT, 
    Operator VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #data
    VALUES 
          ('Tiger', 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 0, 10, 0, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 0, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 0, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 3, NULL)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 5, 10, 3, 'Sam')  

        , ('Shark', 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, 0, 0, null) 
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, null, 5, null) 
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, 20, 2, null)
        , ('Shark', 2, 3, 20, 2, 'Alex')

        , ('Tiger', 0, 0, 0, 0, null)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 3, 0, 0, null) 
        , ('Tiger', 1, null, null, 5, null)
        , ('Tiger', 1, 3, 20, 10, 'Sam') 
        , ('Tiger', 1, 3, 20, 2, 'Sam')


SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator
FROM (
  SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY Device, Hall, EquipNo
            ORDER BY HitCount DESC, 
                     (CASE WHEN EquipNo  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN LocNo    IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN Operator IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
          ) as RN
  FROM #data
) S
WHERE S.RN = 1
```

However, the result of running the query is:

| Device | Hall | EquipNo | LocNo | HitCount | Operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shark | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | null |
| Shark | 2 | 3 | null | 5 | null |
| Tiger | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | null |
| Tiger | 1 | null | null | 5 | null |
| Tiger | 1 | 0 | 10 | 0 | null |
| Tiger | 1 | 3 | 20 | 10 | Sam |
| Tiger | 1 | 5 | 10 | 3 | Sam |

Device must have a value that is not empty string.
Hall and EquipNo also must have a value that is not zero.

So the desired result should be (order is not important):

| Device | Hall | EquipNo | LocNo | HitCount | Operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tiger | 1 | 5 | 10 | 3 | Sam |
| Shark | 2 | 3 | Null | 5 | Null |
| Tiger | 1 | 3 | 20 | 10 | Sam |

Thx.

Comment: This code is wrong you will never need to drop a table with # at the start of it -- they are unique by session.  Right now if two sessions are running the 2nd one will think a table exists (because your search does not include session information) and try and fail to drop it -- creating an error.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @Hogan It works if I have only one session. But I believe you are right, because I noticed sometimes it's not working when I open a second tab/query in ssms. Thx for the info, now I understand why I was getting error. But in my case, the If condition was false even though I had a temp table created.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windowing functions to solve this

```
SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator
FROM (
  SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY Device, Hall, EquipNo
            ORDER BY HitCount DESC, 
                     (CASE WHEN EquipNo  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN LocNo    IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN Operator IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
          ) as RN,
  FROM #temp
) S
WHERE S.RN = 1
```

As you can see we partition by Device, Hall, EquipNo as you requested.  Then to pick the item we use the order by -- we first order with the largest HitCount being first and next by the sum of non-null values being the largest.  This gives the results you asked for when we only select the first item (those with a RN of 1) from the sub-query.

---

Update based on comments

```
SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator
FROM (
  SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY Device
            ORDER BY HitCount DESC, 
                     (CASE WHEN EquipNo  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN LocNo    IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN Operator IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
          ) as RN,
  FROM #temp
) S
WHERE S.RN = 1
```

Comment: Thx Hogan for the answer. I believe it is the correct answer, however, when I tried it in https://dbfiddle.uk and another site, they both give me a syntax error near '(' on the line ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...  I'll try it tomorrow at work. thx again.

Comment: The third line of the example query needs a comma after `... HitCount, Operator`.

Comment: @O.Jones thx. Yes that was the problem. But also the comma at the end of `)as RN,` needs to be deleted.

Comment: @Hogan the result set is not accurate. Instead of 3 records I get 7 records. Well, it's at least a good start. I maybe able to get the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: The final syntax error is due to case statements not having "Then" keyword. For example `CASE WHEN EquipNo  IS NOT NULL 1 ELSE 0 END` should be `CASE WHEN EquipNo  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @SalehAlAbbas -- I fixed the typos -- I apologize.  If you are still getting unexpected results can you post the query you are using and the test data and I will fix.

Comment: @Hogan I've updated the question with the query and the test data. Please, see the "Update" section in the question, or You can run the query here: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/mNX_gZ99).  Don't apologize. I'm honored that you are taking the time to help me.

Comment: In your description you say that "The data can be grouped logically by Device, Hall and EquipNo" but in your example you are grouping by device only.  If you want to see the results you show change my query to say `PARTITION BY Device` in the sub-query @SalehAlAbbas

Comment: @Hogan I'm not sure what example you are referring to. But I'm showing the desired result in the question and the grouping is based on Device, Hall and EquipNo. In any case, I answered my question with the query needed. I couldn't edit your answer. I only needed to add more conditions in the Where clause. Thanks a Million for your help :)

Comment: @SalehAlAbbas -- see my update above

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question but I'm marking Hogan's answer as the correct one because I couldn't edit his answer and I got the solution through him and Maybe I wasn't able to clarify my question well. What was remaining is to ensure that Device, Hall and EquipNo have valid values which are Non-Null and non-zero numbers and non-empty strings.  Here is the query I was looking for:

```
SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator
FROM (
  SELECT  Device, Hall, EquipNo, LocNo, HitCount, Operator,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY Device, Hall, EquipNo
            ORDER BY HitCount DESC, 
                     (CASE WHEN EquipNo  IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN LocNo    IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                      CASE WHEN Operator IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
          ) as RN
  FROM #data
  WHERE Device <> '' AND Device IS NOT NULL
    AND Hall <> 0 AND Hall IS NOT NULL
    AND EquipNo <> 0 AND EquipNo IS NOT NULL
) S
WHERE S.RN = 1
```

Thanks Hogan.

Comment: I think you want to put the where statement on the inner query here.  But look at my answer -- I updated it to show what I meant

Comment: That's True and Done.

Comment: @Hogan .. I did see the updated query and tried it out. The problem with it is that I'll end up with one record for each device. But I need to consider that when a Device is used in different Halls and/or with different Equipment then I need to include that in the result. In other word, for each combination of Device, Hall, EquipNo I need to get one row. This is why we need to partition by Device,hall and EquipNo.

Comment: ok -- in that case take your code and put the where items in the inner select -- this will be faster and give the same results.